# Calculate the list of the futures and and return the result future

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I have a function which takes futures `Future[A]*` and I want it to return a `Future[List[A]]`.

```
def singleFuture[T](futures: List[Future[A]]): Future[List[A]] = {
  val p = Promise[T]
  futures filter { _ onComplete { case x => p complete x /*????*/ } }
  p.future
}
```

And I also want the result future of type `Future[List[A]]` becomes completed immediately after the list futures `List[Future[A]]` have been completed.

That code doesn't work. I figure I should use `flatMap` here because there should be 2 internal loops: one for the future and one for promise. But how?

I'd like not use **for** comprehension here because I'd like to understand the process at the deeper lever.

Comment: "And I also want the result future of type Future[List[A]] becomes completed immediately after the list futures List[Future[A]] have been completed." then there is no point in returning a future of list? rather a list of A?

Comment: @StefanKunze, there is, I need it for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use foldRight to achieve this:

```
def singleFuture[A](futures: List[Future[A]]): Future[List[A]] = {

    val p = Promise[List[A]]()
    p.success(List.empty[A])

    val f = p.future // a future containing empty list.

    futures.foldRight(f) { 
       (fut, accum) =>  // foldRight means accumulator is on right.

        for {
           list <- accum;  // take List[A] out of Future[List[A]]
           a    <- fut     // take A out of Future[A]
        }
        yield (a :: list)   // A :: List[A]
    }
}
```

if any future in futures list fails, a <- fut will fail, resulting in accum being set to failed future.

If you want to avoid using for, you can either expand it to flatMap as follows:

```
  accum.flatMap( list => fut.map(a => a :: list))
```

Or you can use, async-await (noting that it is still an experimental feature).

```
def singleFuture[T](futures: List[Future[T]]): Future[List[T]] = async {

  var localFutures = futures
  val result = ListBuffer[T]()
  while (localFutures != Nil) {
        result += await { localFutures.head } 
        localFutures = localFutures.tail
  }
  result.toList
}
```

Comment: `// take List[A] out of Future[List[A]]` I think it should be `// take Future[A] out of List[Future[A]]` because it's iterating through `List[Future[A]]`

Comment: type of accum is same as type of f, which is Future[List[A]]. the iteration over List[Future[A]] is producing fut.

Comment: You're right. We can also call foldLeft instead by moving "fut" to the right and "accum" to the left and it would the same, correct?

Comment: But when you're calling `p.success(List.empty[A])`, doesn't it make "p" to remember it's as an empty list? As I know, once we write anything to Promise, it can't be changed anymore.

Comment: p.success(List.empty[A]) means that its future will contain List[A]. In this case an empty list of A. p's future always retains this same empty list. But we are using it only as seed value for the fold.

Comment: Could you please explain what the difference between the functions `success` and `successful` for Promise is?

Comment: "success" is the method in trait Promise that completes a promise with given value. "successful" is a method on companion object which returns a newly created promise which is already completed with given value. This is the implementation: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/concurrent/Promise.scala#L1

Comment: But how can we iterate through "fs" if we already have completed its future by calling "success" at Promise "p"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42186/discussion-between-shyamendra-solanki-and-marius-kavansky)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask. What do I do if I want the resulting Future to fail if **any** of the input futures fails? That is to say, only if **all** the futures "fs" succeed, the resulting Future succeeds also. For now if case of error it will succeed anyway with an empty list.

Comment: It works as you intend. If any future fails, the for comprehension results a future with failure, not with empty list.

Comment: @Marius Kavnsky:
"You're right. We can also call foldLeft instead by moving "fut" to the right and "accum" to the left and it would the same, correct?"

If you will use foldLeft order of list will be reversed

Answer (score 8):

This is already implemented for you:

```
def singleFuture[T](futures: List[Future[A]]): Future[List[A]] = Future.sequence(futures)
```

You can, of course, look at the implementation of sequence:

```
def sequence[A, M[_] <: TraversableOnce[_]](in: M[Future[A]])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[Future[A]], A, M[A]], executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[A]] = {
  in.foldLeft(Promise.successful(cbf(in)).future) {
    (fr, fa) => for (r <- fr; a <- fa.asInstanceOf[Future[A]]) yield (r += a)
  } map (_.result())
}
```

This can be simplified if you only want to deal with lists, and not with anything that has foldLeft:

```
def sequence[A](in: List[Future[A]]): Future[List[A]] = {
  in.foldRight[Future[List[A]](Promise.successful(Nil) {
    (fa, fr) => for { r <- fr; a <- fa } yield (a :: r)
  }
}
```

Comment: well, it uses "for" which I want to avoid.

Comment: by the way, how do I failure the resulting future if one of the input future failures?