# Why does this list-of-futures to future-of-list transformation compile and work?

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

*Disclaimer: the code snippet below relates to one of ongoing Coursera courses.
Let's consider it's posted just for a learning purpose and should not be used for submitting as a solution for one's homework assignment.*

As the comment below states, we need to transform a list of Futures to a single Future of a list. More than that, the resulting Future should fail if at least one of input futures failed.

I met the following implementation and I don't understand it completely.

```
/** Given a list of futures `fs`, returns the future holding the list of values of all the futures from `fs`.
 *  The returned future is completed only once all of the futures in `fs` have been completed.
 *  The values in the list are in the same order as corresponding futures `fs`.
 *  If any of the futures `fs` fails, the resulting future also fails.
 */
def all[T](fs: List[Future[T]]): Future[List[T]] = 
             fs.foldRight(Future(Nil:List[T]))((f, fs2) =>
  for {
    x <- f
    xs <- fs2
  } yield (x::xs))
```

In particular, I don't understand the next things in it:

1. Where does `Future[T] -> T` transformation happen? It looks like `xs <- fs2` is the only place we touch initial `Futures`, and each of `xs` type should be `Future[T]` (but somehow it becomes just `T`).
2. How are failures handled? It looks like the resulting `Future` object does fail when one of the input `Futures` fails.

Comment: It is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20280032/332087

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Say f is a `Future[T]`, then writing

```
for {
 t <- f
}  yield List(t)
```

will store the result of the Future f in t - therefor t is of type T. The yield turns it into a List[T], and the type of the whole for-comprehension ends up being Future[List[T]]. So the for-comprehension is where you extract your Ts from your `Futures`,  do something with them, and put them back in a Future (OK, I'm simplifying a little bit here).

It's equivalent to

```
f.map(t => List(t))
```

2) If your Future f contains a Failure, then the for-comprehension will just return this failed Future instead of executing the yield.

As a general note, for-comprehension in Scala is just sugar that can be rewritten with `map, flatMap, filter, foreach`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an English-speaking right-hander, so normally I foldLeft, but each step of the fold looks like:

```
Fn flatMap ((x: T) => Fs map (xs => x :: xs))
```

Your value is `x`.

The function is applied on success, which explains why a failure stops you cold:

```
scala> timed(Await.ready(all(List(Future{Thread sleep 5*1000; 1},Future(2),Future{Thread sleep 10*1000; 3})), Duration.Inf))
res0: (Long, scala.concurrent.Awaitable[List[Int]]) = (10002419021,scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@2a8025a0)

scala> timed(Await.ready(all(List(Future{Thread sleep 5*1000; 1},Future(???),Future{Thread sleep 10*1000; 3})), Duration.Inf))
res1: (Long, scala.concurrent.Awaitable[List[Int]]) = (5000880298,scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3750d517)
```

Notice that the failing version short-circuits.

See the ScalaDoc for flatMap for both bits of information.

Edit: I was speaking cautiously because it is Coursera work, but more plainly, this requirement is not met: "The returned future is completed only once all of the futures in `fs` have been completed."